# Specifying type of array on right side of expression

Tags: c

With the following:

```
typedef struct Person_ {
    char* name;
    char* parents[2];
} Person;

int main(void)
{
    Person jack = {.name="Jack", .parents={"Jim", "Julia"}};
    Person tom = {.name="Tom", .parents={"Terry", "Tina"}};
    Person friends[2] = (Person[2]) {jack, tom};
}
```

I get this error:

> error: array initialized from non-constant array expression 
> Person friends[2] = (Person[2]) {jack, tom};

I know that I can initialize `friends` as:

```
Person friends[2] = {jack, tom};
```

But why isn't it possible to annotate the type on the right side with an array like I would be able to (though redundantly) with another type such as:

```
int x = (int) 4;
char *y = (char*) "Hi";

// invalid
// int z[2] = (int[2]) {1,2};
```

Comment: You just can't.  The language doesn't permit assigning one array to another, and it similarly doesn't permit initializing one array with another.  (The initializer `{jack, tom}` in your other example is not itself an array.)

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, thank you. Could you please explain what you mean by: `{jack, tom} is not itself an array` ? -- or do you just mean that the compound literal doesn't 'reduce' to an array so cannot be used for the initialization?

Comment: The error message you get from the compiler is quite misleading. The initializer for an array must be only a brace-enclosed list, or a string literal (only for character arrays).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this statement

```
Person friends[2] = (Person[2]) {jack, tom};
```

`(Person[2]) {jack, tom}` is a compound literal.

From C11 Standard - Compound literals#6.5.2.5p5

> 5 The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the initializer list. ....

So, this `(Person[2]) {jack, tom}` will result in an unnamed array of `Person` type initialised from the initialiser list `{jack, tom}`. You cannot intialize an array from another array.

From C11 Standard - Compound literals#6.7.9p16

> 16 Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace- enclosed list of initializers for the elements or named members.

This `{jack, tom}` is initialiser list whereas this `(Person[2]) {jack, tom}` is compound literal.

The compound literal results in an unnamed array, initialises it with given values and creates a pointer point to first element of array. So, in this statement

```
int *a1  = (int[2]) {1,2};
```

`(int[2]) {1,2}` will result in an unnamed array of `2` `int` initialised with value `{1, 2}` and create pointer to initial element of unnamed array.

From C11 Standard#6.3.2.1p3

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. ....

Comment: @H.S. I guess one of my questions is why `int *a1  = (int[2]) {1,2};` is allowed, but `int a2[] = (int[2]) {1,2};` is not and gives the error: "array initialized from non-constant array expression" ?

Comment: @H.S. ok, so basically the only initialization that an array can accept is an "array literal", if that's such a thing, is that correct?

Comment: @David542 There is nothing like "array literal" in C. The brace enclosed list of initialiser is called initialiser list. For details about array initialisation check [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) and for struct/union initialisation check [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization).